# to which resource class should this http get request be forwarded to?

Tags: java, http, restlet, http-get

Restlet's concept relies on using a unique URI for every resource, and every resource has its own resource class that defines the needed functions ( get,set, put, .. etc).

lets say in the database I have three tables,

- companies
- departments
- employees

in this case, I have the following resources :

- company
- companies
- department
- departments
- employee
- employees

In case the client wants to find the name of employees in department X in the companies that are in city Y , what I want to say that, here the HTTP get request should be forwarded to which URI of the six available ones ? this HTTP get request is not associated with only one resource (table) but with multiple ones at the same time. How could this be configured ?
I hope you were able to catch my question.

edit :

in other words, in which resource class should the function or method that accesses the three tables in the database be placed ?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion employees b/c you need employees names. You can also return all employee info. The REST call should should go to output related entities.

Comment: I didnt really get your answer, anyways, I edited my question

Comment: @SLA: If your are specific to said scenario then I would recommend "Employees".

Comment: I would agree that it should be "Employees". Add filtering parameters to restrict employee for specific cities, for example, http://REST_URL/Employees?where=city:sydney,chicago